# JQuery not loaded after RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'll cut right to the chase.

After I call RedirectToAction to any of my Action-methods, my JQuery libraries are not loaded until after the page has rendered. (Note: a direct route to the Action Method loads the libraries correctly). I'm not using renderSection for my scripts at the moment, but load the bundles in the header, in the _Layout.cshtml document:

```
<head>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
```

This goes for all the libraries I try to load in the header, by the way.
I do see any reason why it wouldn't work when I'm redirection. Maybe I don't understand the RedirectToAction method correctly, in which case I would be very happy with an explanation.

An example of the redirect I use, from my controllers:

```
return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", new{orderId = order.Id});
```

(Keep in mind, that this problem persists trough all my controllers, and all actions)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you are saying your jQuery libraries are not loaded, do you mean a particular function in your jQuery or .. how do you check if it's not loaded ? Please add the code that doesn't load.

Comment: Ajax? Partials? can you please provide whole controller action and what exactly does not load please ?

Comment: @Ali - The libraries are loaded, but not until after page has been rendered. This results in errors like "$ is not a function". This goes for all the Script libraries I'm including in my bundle (in the header).

Comment: which jquery you want yo use specifically in .cstml page? have you check the reference is correct or not?

Comment: @Bart. It goes for all actions in my application. There is nothing special about them, and they work fine as long as I access them through their respective URL's - just not when I use RedirectToAction from other actions.

Comment: can you show the view?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. There must be something that you are not telling us. The scripts cannot load *"after the page has rendered"* in the way that you describe. There isn't enough code provided to work with. Look at the javascript errors you're getting and also look at what order things are loading and if there are any 404s.

Comment: Here is the page, when it's loaded correctly (trought direct URL request):
http://imgur.com/cp5jAdd

And here is the same page, after the form has been submitted, and the redirect is done:
http://imgur.com/LVc1ttF

Here is the Jquery error:

http://imgur.com/2H65DCs

Comment: (In the above case, It was the library "raty". But it's the same deal on other pages, where I use other libraries)

Comment: Are you using ajax updates? If so, you may need to register the jquery scripts as startup scripts in the updatepanel.

Comment: Found this issue. Posted it as answer. Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, after studying my Network tab in firebug. Here was the problem:

On redirects after form-posts, I load a jquery script via TempData. I accidentally made an external reference to jquery in that partial view's script.

**Controller:**

```
                TempData["Message"] = new GenericMessage()
            {
                Message = "You need to select a date",
                MessageType = GenericMessages.danger
            };

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

**Partial View Script:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $('div.alert-generic').delay(3500).fadeOut(); }); </script>
<div class="alert alert-block alert-@genericMessage.MessageType.ToString() alert-generic">
    <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">&times;</a>
    @Html.Raw(genericMessage.Message)
</div>
```

This caused JQuery to be loaded twice (in different versions), on redirects.
After I removed the reference from the script, it all worked perfectly again. Thanks to those of you who tried to help me out, and I apologise for not seeing this error my self, before now.